# regex url with multiple query strings for google analytics goal

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm new to regex and I'm trying to use google analytics to track conversions on 
https://foo.com to 
https://signup.foo.com/signup/signup.php?step=signup&nats=MzAwMDk2Mi&switched=1&strack=0&tpl=page_approval

I need to match anything on signup.foo.com with the parameter tpl=page_approval

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: https://signup.foo.com/signup/signup.php\?step=signup&/.*\tpl=page

Comment: this seems to work but shows a 0% conversion rate when I add it as a goal in GA: https://signup.foo.com/signup/signup.php\(.*)tpl=page_approval

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

`signup\.foo\.com\/\S*[?&]tpl=page_approval\b\S*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0mfjNk/2/)

**Explained:**

```
signup\.foo\.com\/  # domanin + bar
\S*   # 1 or more non-whitespace characters
[?&]tpl=page_approval  # a '?' or '&' character + rpl=page_approbal
\b    # bareword
\S*   # Use this if you must match the whole url.
```

Comment: Thanks. this seems to be matching when i test it at https://www.regextester.com, but for some reason is still showing a 0% conversion rate when I set it as a goal in google analytics. it might be because its on a different domain

Comment: Did you change foo.bar to your real domain?

Comment: yes. I think its an issue with tracking across different domains now. Your answer is very helpful though